# How do I determined a User Environment Variable in YAML file for Microsoft Hosted Agent?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, ui-automation

As per title above.

I am trying to mimic my automation setup on my local machine to match the automation i have running using Microsoft Hosted Agent machine.

This is how it set up in my local machine. therefore when the automation inserts "%repoic%" in a file explorer and the select folder button is pressed, it will open the desired folder

[image]

Now, I need to do the same using the Microsoft Hosted Agent to run my automation. Would anyone give me a clue on how this can be done? Is it simply do the following within my DevOps Pipeline's YAML file?

[image]

cheers!

Comment: Fyi, my attempt above doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your requirement, you need to set the Environment variable and use it to navigate to path of the agent machine.

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, you can set the Pipeline variable as the screenshot show in the question.

Then you can use the format: `$(variablename)` to use the Pipeline variable.

Or you can use the format: `%NAME%` for batch and `$env:NAME` in PowerShell to use the Pipeline Environment Variable.  Refer to this doc: [Environment Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables)

Here is an example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  testpath: ./src/app/head

steps:

- powershell:  Get-Location
  workingDirectory: $(testpath)
```

**Result:**

[image]

OR you can use the environment variable in Pipeline.

Example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  testpath: ./src/app/head

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      cd %testpath%
```

Comment: hey there, Thanks for the explanation.

That giving me more sense on how to tackle my issue here.

Using the idea above, I ended up using $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) to ensure I am on the right directory before extending the path to where I want it to be.